# SVMono Example Environment

Tags: environments, sv-classes

I am writing a book using Overleaf with the SVMono Document Class (since the book will be published by Springer-Nature). The problem I am encountering concerns the "Example" environment (Section 2.7 of the SVMono Document Class Reference Guide).

Here is what is going on.

I have 6 example problems (1.1, 1.2, ..., 1.6) in Chapter 1 that are written using

\begin{example}
...
\end{example}

After these example problems in Chapter 1, there are two figures with caption labels Fig. 1.1 and Fig. 1.2.  However, when I reference these figures in the text using \ref{reference name}, they appear in the pdf as Fig. 1.7 and Fig. 1.8.  It seems that the counter is not being reset somehow. I've tested all of the options in the declaration of the document class (envcountsame, envcountchap,envcountsect, envcountresetchap, envcountresetsect)

I am just a novice with Latex.  Any insight into this issue would be most welcome. Thanks.
Tony

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide an small but complete document  example, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: A reproducible document would be helpful. When I try `\documentclass{svmono}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{example}\label{ex1}First example\end{example}
\begin{example}\label{ex2}Second example\end{example}
\begin{figure}\fbox{First figure}\caption{A figure}\label{fig1}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\fbox{Second figure}\caption{Another figure}\label{fig2}\end{figure}
See example \ref{ex2} and figure \ref{fig2}.
\end{document}` everything works ok.

Comment: Quite likely this is due to a misplaced `\label` command, which should go ***after*** `\caption{...}` in the `figure` environments.